# How to select catch section select only

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am using try and catch block in my stored procedure. I am selecting some data from few tables in the try block and throwing error with below code in the catch block.

```
SELECT 
    ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber
    ,ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity
    ,ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState
    ,ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure
    ,ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine
    ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;
```

My stored procedure returning following two result sets in case of any error while I needed only second (Highlighted one) result set.

[image]

How can I achieve this is sql\t-sql.

Comment: Put the first in a temp table or declared variables and don't return them.

Comment: But what happened when I need to return in case of no error

Comment: Sorry, you weren't clear that you wanted the first dataset. Check your temp table for a row count, If > 0 then select it, otherwise don't.

Comment: Yes that worked but what still need to figure out many other error scenarios

Comment: Post your entire procedure. That select could be in the catch block only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by WEI_DBA I dump into temp table and selecting data if row count>0. This is working for simple select. Still I need to figure more complex business scenarios.